# UIView not animating correctly when UILabel is added to it

Tags: objective-c, animation, autolayout

I'm animating a custom view off screen using a constraint on view's top edge.

The view is:

```
@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

    _label = [UILabel new];
    [_label setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    _label.text = @"text";
    [self addSubview:_label];

    [self updateConstraints];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)updateConstraints
{
  NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_label);
  [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[_label]"
                                                               options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:views]];

  [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_label]"
                                                               options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:views]];
  [super updateConstraints];
}

@end
```

The constraint for animating myView on its parent view is:

```
_myViewTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_myView
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:self.view
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:-kMyViewVisibleHeight];

[self.view addConstraint:_myViewTopConstraint];
```

The animation on the top edge constraint is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    self.myViewTopConstraint.constant = kScreenHeight;
    [self.myView layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:nil];
```

When the label and constraints in MyView is commented out, the animation works perfectly. But when the label and constraints are there, the animation is sped up significantly, maybe 5x or more.

Why does this happen? Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. layoutIfNeeded must be called on myView's parent view in the animation block.

```
 [self.myView layoutIfNeeded];
```

changed to

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```